# using date across continents and devices?

Tags: ios, node.js, mongodb, date

I'm developing a simple "todo" list application using node.js, mongodb for backend and IOS application as a front-end along with browser based interface.

> There are two (2) attributes, a todo item text and a due date

The application flow is as follows,

> 1) IOS Application user enters a text along with due date (local date), or
>
> 2) User enters todo text in a (form) browser along with a due date (local date)

So my question is,

> a) Should IOS application (uses datepicker) or browser creates a UTC string date from local date to send to the server?
>
> b) Should the date be saved in mongodb as UTC String and then convert as needed to the local format? This is what I'm thinking but not sure.

Any help clarifying this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should always store dates as UTC. That way you only need to know the local Timezone to display it. If you store local time then you need to know the Timezone of the stored date

Comment: Only use local times and dates in your UI. Use ISO-8601 date format for strings if you have to store dates in this way. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601.

Comment: Does that mean to store the date as "UTC String" format in the database? Can it be converted to local date on any device or accessed in a browse from any geo location?